# Sort and group by and find max of each group in Java 8

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I have an object which has a name and a score. I want to sort the elements by name and find the max score for that name.

For example below are the objects (*name*, *score*):

```
(a, 3)
(a, 9)
(b, 7)
(b, 10)
(c, 8)
(c, 3)
```

The output should be:

```
(a, 9)
(b, 10)
(c, 8)
```

I am able to sort using the below code, but I am not able to find out *max*

```
List<Record> result = list.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Record::score))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Record::name, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toList()))
        .values().stream()
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to chain `maxBy` to the `groupinhBy` collectior:

```
Map<String,Record> result = 
    list.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Record::score))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Record::name, 
                                       LinkedHashMap::new,
                                       Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Record::getScore))));
```

And if you only care about the `Record` instances, you can obtain the `values()` of that `Map`.

Comment: Thanks Eran !! one more question, what if I want to store it as Map<string, Integer> as in Map<name, score> ...(I am very new to java )

Comment: @Shraddha The easiest way is to stream over the entrySet of the `Map<String,Record>`  and use `.collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,e->e.getValue().getScore()))`. There might be a way to do it all in a single stream pipeline, but I can't think of it right now.

Comment: @Shraddha perhaps you can use `collectingAndThen`. Try the pipeline in my answer, but with `.collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.groupingBy(...),Record::getScore)`. I'm not sure of the syntax, but something similar should work.

Comment: yes, I tried that already but its saying collectingAndThen method not applicable here.. May be I am also using wrong syntax.

Comment: @Shraddha I think I chained it in the wrong place. Try to replace `Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Record::getScore))` (of my original answer) with `Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.maxBy(...),Record::getScore)`.

Comment: @Shraddha sorry about that, I can't test this without having the code of your Record class.

Comment: `Map<String,Record>` should be `Map<String,Optional<Record>>`? According to https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#maxBy(java.util.Comparator)

Comment: First sorted operation is not required for my case. Can anyone please explain the use of that?

Answer (score 7):

@Eran's answer is very good. Nevertheless, I would proceed the other way round by first grouping and then reducing:

```
List<Record> result = list.stream()
                              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Record::getName, 
                                      Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Record::getScore))))
                              .values().stream()
                              .map(Optional::get)
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

A disadvantage here is that you have to call optional#get. But since a group resulting from groupingBy will never be empty you can call Optional#get without geting an exception.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for grouping if only one value (score) is collected per key (name). We can directly use `Collectors.toMap()` with its three-argument overload and provide a `mergeFunction`.

```
    Map<String, Integer> hiScoreByName = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Record::getName,
            Record::getScore,
            BinaryOperator.maxBy(Integer::compareTo)
    ));
    // {a=9, b=10, c=8}
```